# Download old attachment file on Gmail marked as a virus

Tags: gmail, gmail-attachments

I have an old file attachment (`file.zip`) in my Gmail account. I want to download it but now Gmail says that the file that I want to download is blocked because it is a virus. I think one trick is to forward it to another mail provider but I can't forward it for the same reason. Anyone know a trick to download that file?

Comment: I feel you, what a pain! Happened to me a couple of times.

Comment: That was a duplicate but not the answer that i want. I think the fastes way is to download it from my mobile gmail account and to take it from my phone! Thank you